# Run Java 8 application on server with Java 7 using docker

Tags: java, linux, docker

I have application wrote in Java 8, and now I have to deploy this application on server which has jdk 1.7 but I was using lambdas, optionals and streams and I'm looking for a method to run this application on this server.

Is it possible to create on this server docker container with jdk 1.8 and run my application in this container?

Comment: Well if you have root access to the server, why not upgrade to Java 8?

Comment: If there is already a docker installation on the server, then yes, it makes a sense.  If not I would go for installing second JDK and use it exclusively for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes.

You'll need to have some kind of container runtime on that server, e.g. Docker. All you need would be to create an image based on a Dockerfile similar to this one:

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN adduser -Dh /home/app-user app-user
USER app-user
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./path/to/app.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
CMD ["--spring.profiles.active=prod"]
```

Base images for Apache Tomcat are available, too: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

The example app might help you getting started with a more complex setup: https://github.com/dockersamples/atsea-sample-shop-app/

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to my initial answer it can be done. [Docker store](https://store.docker.com/images/tomcat) has images availible.

Only done partial testing with functionality though.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong - Docker actually can encapsulate different JREs on the same machine, even without any JRE being installed on the host.

Comment: You could be right, ill have to look deeper into it when given the time.

Comment: No problem, the way I leaned of how docker works made me assume it wasn't possible, I'm glad you called me out on that, thank you.